# Class variables inheritance in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance

I understand that this question has been raised many times already. But I can't find the complete guide about all those kinds of variables. I've found a couple of articles that compare class variables vs class instance variables, but what about instance variables?
So, what is the difference between: **instance variables**, **class variables** and **class instance variables**? What kind of variables are inheritable and what are not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An *instance variable* is, well, a variable that belongs to *one* specific object (aka instance). Inheritance is irrelevant in this case, since objects can't inherit from anything, only classes can.

*Class instance variables* don't exist. Classes are objects just like any other, so they can have instance variables just like any other object. When a class has an instance variable, this is sometimes called a class instance variable, but it's just an instance variable. So, again, it can't be inherited.

*Class variables* are strange beasts. They are shared among

- the class itself
- all instances of the class
- all subclasses of the class
- all instances of all subclasses of the class
- all subclasses of all subclasses of the class
- all instances of all subclasses of all subclasses of the class
- … and so on …

They are really more like global variables, considering how widely they are shared.

You can call this sharing *inheritance*, but I don't think that's a useful term. There is no polymorphic dispatch, no message sending, no overriding.

In Ruby, the term *inheritance* really only makes sense with *methods*, not with variables.

Answer (score 0):

Instance Variables are variables which are the ones whose data varies with each instance of the object.

Class variables are those which are shared across all instances of a class. Actually every instance points to the same value and change is seen across all the class instances.